# Can I scope a permission or role assignment to a specific domain/organisation in CASL.js

Tags: typescript, authentication, casl

I’m currently in the process of building a solution with CASL.js. In this solution, there are a number of sellers. Let’s call these `merchant1` and `merchant2`. A merchant is like an organisation or domain. I’ve been reading this tutorial which almost meets my goal of restricting a merchant’s access to their own data with a particular permission derived via a role:

https://casl.js.org/v5/en/cookbook/roles-with-static-permissions

Conditions are used here to restrict access. The issue is I would like users to be able to have different roles for different merchants, almost like a domain scoped role. For example, the role assignments might look like this:

- `(user1, administrator, merchant1)`
- `(user1, reader, merchant2)`

If I use data from the `user`,
for say a condition on `user.merchantId`, it’s not possible to determine which merchant the role and related permission was assigned for. As far as I can see, the check would need to be:

`Can(‘view’, ‘order’, { merchantId: permission.merchantId })`

…or something similar. I haven’t really found a documented way to approach this.

https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/conditions-in-depth

Has anyone solved this problem of scoped role assignments in CASL.js before? Otherwise, do you have any recommendations for another - ideally TypeScript - library that can handle this?

Comment: Depending on the amount of merchants single user can manage, you fetch all merchant ids for specific user and define conditions using $in operator

Comment: How would you determine which roles map to which merchantIds though?

Comment: I suppose you could attach all the roles and permissions to the user and query for the appropriate scoped permission using a custom condition. You’d lose a lot of the elegance of CASL though.

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi I had an inspiring discussion with a colleague. We're going to try the following:

1) force the user to select which merchantId to use for the session
2) when we query for that user in our CASL middle-ware, we'll join on a `userMerchantRole` table. This way we'll only retrieve the roles associated with the user for that merchant. We'd do so in our equivalent of this query https://casl.js.org/v5/en/cookbook/roles-with-static-permissions#putting-together

I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hello, did you figure this one out? I am looking for the same exact thing

Comment: Hey @FotisParaskevopoulos. What we ended up doing was creating a role with a scope for a specific merchant. We created some middleware that accepts an object - like an order - and performs the rule assertion based on this using the CASL library.  queries the users roles to do so. For example, given order 123 with a merchant ID of ABC, get the roles for this user, setup their abilities based on the roles that they have to view an order with the merchant ID (merchant ID in role goes here), and then assert `ability.can(view, order, merchantId == order.merchantId)`. This works well.